# kernel_task hundreds of % CPU yet cpu frequency is being lowered

Tags: performance, cpu

I'm trying to solve the mystery of a crazy high cpu usage on kernel_task.

MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012), 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7, Yosemite 10.10.2

I saw some advice to download the Intel Power Gadget. That showed me that the my CPU is slowing way down. How do I fix this? When this happens, I can sometimes cycle the power on the MBP. But this is driving me crazy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does the temperature graph show for the same period, as it slows down?

Comment: Mine (Late 2013 MBP) seems stuck permanently at that same 0.80 GHz level. CPU utilization is 60-100%. Temps are reasonable – 50-60C... 

Answer (score 14):

Apple documents this.

> Activity Monitor may show that a process named kernel_task is using a large percentage of your CPU, and during this time you may notice a lot of fan activity. This process helps manage temperature by making the CPU less available to processes that are using the CPU intensely. In other words, kernel_task responds to conditions that cause your CPU to become too hot. When the temperature decreases, kernel_task automatically reduces its activity.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203184

You might want to [reset the SMC one time](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) to be sure it's not stuck and providing incorrect temperature readings to the processor.

If the SMC or high temperatures is the root cause, you should be able to correlate the various internal temperature sensors and physical measurement of the case and exhaust air temperature with the design throttling of the kernel scheduling and the clock rate adjustments the chipset is designed to make in response to thermal measurements.

Worst case, you have a hardware issue with faulty temperature sensors or an out-of-spec CPU that generates more heat than it should for a given GHz clock rate.

Comment: Hi @bmike, I also got the problem. Whenever I use external monitor, it will make the kernel_task that high. Or to be more precise, whenever I use GPU. Is it normal?
I use MacBook Pro Retina 2016.

Comment: What proof is there that heat is the actual cause in this case?

Comment: @ash In this thread https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363933/297783 one of the comments points to the code in MacOS, in `kern/thread_info.h` and `kern/thread.h` there are values `TH_FLAGS_GLOBAL_FORCED_IDLE` and `TH_OPT_GLOBAL_FORCED_IDLE` which is described as "Thread performs forced idle for thermal control"

Comment: In fact here's the source: https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.71.2/osfmk/kern/thread.h.auto.html

Comment: @drkvogel  Thank you for the reference.  I now believe strongly that my MBP (which I just finally, very happily replaced with a Linux workstation) has some other problem related to hardware.  The overheating doesn't have to be the CPU.  In my case, it often appeared related to charging.  It could also be faulty sensors.  I did open the case and remove a significant amount of dust recently - not sure yet it that helped, but there definitely was a good amount of it.

Comment: BTW, to give a little more context - for anyone researching this issue - in my case, the problem happened in all the following states: charging (i.e. on power), discharging (i.e. disconnected from power), clamshell, open screen.  And it often triggered on changing between these states.

Comment: Github link to source code: https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/e7776783b89a353188416a9a346c6cdb4928faad/osfmk/kern/thread.h#L314

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had a MBP used continuously for 3 years. The local Mac store opened the case and cleared out the dust. That FIXED the problem!!!!

Basically the extra dust caused the CPU to overheat.

Answer (score 0):

My current MB Pro Retina(late 2013) suffers from this. I installed Ubuntu on my laptop just so that I can barely run the browser and terminal.

The reason behind my laptops throttling seems to be faulty temperature sensors. Some of the sensors are reporting a reading of -127C which starts the throttling. I have compiled temperature readings from sensors in this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/afm-sayem/1d5b23e8e481722f9d169a63dfee3c93).

So far, there's no solution in sight. I have tried cleaning, modifying kernel extensions and resetting SMC.

---

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - From Review -