# excessive cpu usage from kernel_task after accidentally ripping Facetime HD camera connector off the logic board

Tags: facetime, cpu, logicboard

Accidentally ripped off the Facetime HD camera cable of the logic board. Now whenever I boot into OS X kernel_task hogs all the cpu (500%).

I could be wrong here, but my hunch is that because no facetime camera is connected, a process is going crazy trying to detect the Facetime camera.

I've taken it to the apple store. Unfortunately they are telling me to replace the logic board. Seems like there must be a hack to disable Facetime HD detection. Not concerned if I don't have a camera. Thanks in advance

Comment: kernel_task using high CPU is usually intentional - to try keep your machine's temperatures down - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179150/kernel-task-hundreds-of-cpu-yet-cpu-frequency-is-being-lowered

Comment: thanks Tetsujin. I never had this issue until I ripped off the camera connector from the logic board. You are correct, I believe it's high because it can't detect the facetime HD camera, but my question is: Is there a way to disable the detection (if that is in fact what is causing kernel_task to use an excessive amount of cpu)

Comment: Are you positive that's the only thing done internally? What were you doing that resulted in the FaceTime connector being ripped off?

Comment: idk, but I'd be tempted to start in console & see if something is obviously yelling

Comment: samh My original issue was some display pixel anomalies, so I opened it up to see if the screen was connected properly. I understand this was a bad idea. Can't be 100% sure, but I'm pretty confident about only messing that connector.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a resolution?