# How to stop throttling

Tags: mac, performance, cpu, cooling

How could I improve the performance of my MacBook and stop throttling?

Although the CPU load is not by 100%, the CPU cores heat up to 100 degrees.
[image: Activity Monitor and HWMonitor]

[image: Info]

Comment: When was the last time it was stripped & cleaned? Those fans are running full tilt, yet failing to keep up.

Comment: @Tetsujin how could I strip the macbook?

Comment: Search ifixit.com - they have teardowns of most Macs

Comment: It's not clear to me that it's throttling.  According to your activity monitor, your usage is 57%, suggesting you've got four of the 8 virtual cores running at 100% (you could see this explicitly if you ordered the Activity Monitor by CPU usage).  And your system has allowed those to heat to ~100C, which is the max allowed temp. To determine throttling, you'd need to see the clock speed at which your CPU is running relative to the base clock.  And for that, you'd want to download the Intel Power Gadget for Mac from Intel's site:  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20

Answer (score 1):

Try using an application called Mac Fan Control , its very helpful.
The site is https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control.

Max out Fans and test performance.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Your ambient temperature is too high. 34 C / 95 F is the problem.

1. Remove any cases, elevate the mac, open the clam shell and get a blower if your room temperature isn’t that hot.
2. Place the Mac in a room cooled. For testing - try to get it to 15 C / 60 F and repeat your measured benchmark or measured load.
3. Consider a trusted companion to examine the heat sinks and renew the thermal paste after cleaning and inspecting the internals. If you are not sure the technician is capable, skip this - everything in your sensors look normal for thermal throttling except I would expect the [kernel task to be soaking all the CPU so you see no idle.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179150/kernel-task-hundreds-of-cpu-yet-cpu-frequency-is-being-lowered)