# Problem with kernel_task

Tags: macos, cpu, kernel, sip

It's about 3 days that I can't do anything with my macbook air because the kernel_task is eating up the CPU. So I found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7253639) but the command `csrutil disable/enable` doesn't work on the terminal (El Capitan) and I found out that some models doesn't know this command but I couldn't find how else I can disable SIP (system integrity protection). 
So the questions is that how can I solve this problem with kernel task?
[image]

Comment: SIP has nothing to do with what's allocating kernel_task.  Can you show us a screen capture of your Activity Monitor?

Comment: @Allan I need to disable SIP for deleting those .kext files. I'll upload a screenshot now.

Comment: Don't delete kexts until you know what the issue is.

Comment: @Allan So what do you suggest here?

Comment: First thing... see this post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179150/kernel-task-hundreds-of-cpu-yet-cpu-frequency-is-being-lowered

Comment: @Allan So finally I could find the right screws, and I reset the SMC. But it didnt solve the problem:/ what should I do now?

Comment: I'm not sure what "screws" have to do with anything, but there's "something" causing kernel_task to temp throttle your CPU.  Try running [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached. Also try running in Safe Mode to see if that solves the problem.  Keep in mind it could be hardware related (a malfunctioning sensor or even SMC chip)

Comment: @Allan My mistake, Actually I meant I could find screwdriver for removing the screws, maybe no need to mention that;) I'm running AHT now, I'll tell the results. Actually its LCD has problem but I dont think that is the reason to the problem.

Comment: Huh?  What?  No idea what you talking about.  <wink> <wink> <nod> <nod>

Answer (score 1):

So after resetting SMC, rebooting safe mode and every other solutions that is suggested on different forums, changing the battery solved the problem!!! By the way, the battery was changed last year and it didnt need repair!!!